# Puppeteer - testing different selectors for page

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to have my puppeteer script iterate through selectors.

The reason being - depending on what I'm querying through my script, I can get slightly different elements on the page.

Essentially I have a page.evaluate method that does the scraping like this

```
    while (currentPage <= pagesToScrape) {

        let newProducts = await page.evaluate(({identified}) => {
          let results = [];

          let items = document.querySelectorAll(
            identified
          );
console.log(items)


          items.forEach((item) => {
            var prod, price;
            if (identified == selectors[0]) {
              prod = item.querySelector("div>div>div>div>div>a>h3").innerText;
              price = item.querySelector("div>div>div>div>div>div>span>span")
                .innerText;
            } else {
              prod = item.querySelector("div>a>h4").innerText;
              price = item.querySelector("div>div>div>div>span>span").innerText;
            }
            results.push({
              Product: prod !== "" ? prod : "",
              Price: price !== "" ? price : "",
            });
          });
          console.log("results");
          console.log(results.length);
          return results;
        });
        product_GSH = product_GSH.concat(newProducts);
        if (currentPage < pagesToScrape) {
          console.log(identified)
          await Promise.all([
            await page.click(buttonSelector),
            await page.waitForSelector(identified),
          ]);
        }
```

Now before the script starts, I need to ensure I have the correct selector.

```
const selectors = ['div[class = "sh-dlr__list-result"',"div[class = 'sh-dgr__content'"]
  //works
  const chooseSelector = await page.waitForFunction((selectors) => {
    for (const selector of selectors) {
      if (document.querySelector(selector) !== null) {
        return selector;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }, {}, selectors);

  const identified = await chooseSelector.jsonValue();
```

console.log(identified)

The issue I'm having is, from within the page.evaluate, I can run the identifier easily and find the correct one to use. But I need to have it parsed at the end of the query again to scrape the next page. When I try to re-assign the variable name to the correct identifier inside the page.evaluate, it doesn't parse it.

When i run this, the code runs, but I cannot change the selector inside the promise at the bottom with page.waitfor (so it works with some pages but when it's the wrong page I can't alternate the selector being chosen). this is the full code fyi.

```
        product_GSH = product_GSH.concat(newProducts);
        if (currentPage < pagesToScrape) {
          await Promise.all([
            await page.click(buttonSelector),

            page.waitForNavigation()
          ]);
        }
        currentPage++;
      }
      browser.close();

      return res.send(product_GSH);
    } catch (e) {
      return res.send(e);
    }
  });
});
```

> I'm thinking one way to solve this issue is to look at the promise.all
>   function and replace it with something slightly different.

Thanks for helping with this issue!

Last question if you can help - How do i make sure when I choose say 5 pages, and there are only 3 pages of results, that it sends the 3 pages. What I'm finding is that if i say there's more pages it doesn't send any response.

Ideally, I'm trying to have this code be able to iterate through different selectors. I've tried a bunch of different methods, and CORS errors and more aside, very lost. It would be good to get some sort of definite error from puppeteer as well!

Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`page.waitForNavigation`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.1/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) along with `page.click(buttonSelector)` promises. Also, to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), you have to pass it actual promises and **not resolved promises** like you're doing:

```js
if (currentPage < pagesToScrape) {
  await Promise.all([
    page.click(buttonSelector),
    page.waitForNavigation()
  ]);
}
```

You can simplify selectors, for example

```html
div[class = "sh-dlr__list-result"
```

can be

```html
div.sh-dlr__list-result
```

The selector

```html
const buttonSelector = "a[id='pnnext']>span[style='display:block;margin-left:53px']";
```

is wrong; you should never rely on style to query a selector; that can easily be dynamic changed; instead you can define it like this

```html
const buttonSelector = "a#pnnext";
```

After we make these changes we'll get the proper results, for example it will output:

```
product_GSH.length 100
product_GSH [...]
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to handle results with less than `pagesToScrape` pages, then you have to look for `buttonSelector` before you perform a click on it like this:

```js
if (currentPage < pagesToScrape && await page.$(buttonSelector) !== null) {
  await Promise.all([
    page.click(buttonSelector),
    page.waitForNavigation()
  ]);
}
```

Comment: @christosLystras Thanks so much, waitfornav worked perfectly >< .

If you could solve one other thing so I've completed what I set out to do, how do i make sure when I choose say 5 pages, and there are only 3 pages of results, that it sends the 3 pages. 

What I'm finding is that if i say there's more pages it doesn't send any response.

Comment: You have to check if `buttonSelector` exists before you click it; if it does not exist, it means that we're on the last page and we don't click it. I've updated my answer, please check it out.

Comment: It's nice you got it working; not sure why you got a downvote, upvoting.

Comment: If possible - it would be sweet if you could remove the full working Puppeteer script part. Probably being paranoid but rather not have all of it online

Comment: Yeah cheers Christos. Now my next step is to put it into lightsail, and work out how to use proxies :)

Comment: I just removed the puppeteer script. Check the answer if it's OK with you. You can also edit it if you think it has information that you don't want to be there.

Answer (score 2):

Promise.all looks like the place to solve this. I'm not the best with promise functions though

Comment: Thanks for that. I think you're probably right, but for some reason when I use different if statements around the promise function, it doesn't parse through the correct identifier.